# Empty output printed in Chrome and chromium

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have a css file and I defined all rules for screen and print (with `@media print`).
Here is some code:

```
/* more css rules above */

@media print
{
    body * {
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    #preview, #preview * { 
        visibility:visible; 
    }
}
```

In IE and Firefox all work great but in chrome and chromium I get an empty page (nothing is printed) Do these browsers need any special cosiderations?

**EDIT:**
I downloaded [this plugin](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/installed/chrome/04/) for Chrome and Chromium that allow me debug the print stylesheet and to my surprise, the plugin show me exactly the same as Firefox and IE.

Comment: Of course you will get an empty page because you are hiding everything in the body (e.g the whole page)

Comment: @Pattle I diplaying the important area, that is, #preview. In Firefox this work fine, just print the #preview area.

Comment: I think maybe in some browsers your first rule takes precedence, that could be the problem

Comment: @Pattle. See my edit. Also, Do you have any idea how I can solve my problem? How can you print in Chrome/Chromium?